# how to host multiple sites under same firebase project hosting with express framework

Tags: firebase, express, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

i am trying to host two different sites under same firebase project.

i am using express framework for functions

for the first site i have done following:

```
firebase init hosting
proceed with an existing project created from console

firebase init functions
proceed with installing all dependencies
```

then i installed express framework

```
npm i express --save
```

my firebase.json file looks like following:

```
{
   "hosting": {
      "public": "public",
      "ignore": [
         "firebase.json",
         "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [{
         "source": "**",
         "function": "front"
       }]
   }
}
```

now i have added another site under same project in hosting section.

so my questions are:
how to connect my second site from cli?
do i need to init another function for new site?
do i need to install another express framework?
what will be the file structure for both site? will it be together or in separate folder?

currently my first site structure is:

```
mainfolder
   -firebase.json
   -public
      -404.html
   -functions
      -index.js
      -node_modules
```

my target is to separate frontend and backend by different domain. that's why i am trying to use two sites under same firebase project.

just to mention again, i am using express framework. separate public files and express files for both site is expected.

please help with a good project structure.

Answer (score 1):

Just create another site inside your firebase console. Then upload the site into the other. as

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9095420?hl=en